# Setting up group constraints for Scipy minimize optimization problem

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python. I'm trying to use the `scipy.minimize` function to optimize a set of weights.

The set of weights are classified into several groups with different group codes. The aggregate weights need to sum up to 100%. Each group's weight can not be more than 50%.

I have 2 sets of test data. The simple one (with a `2` at the end of each variable, e.g. `optResult2`) with 10 variables work as expected.

But the more complicated one, with 50 variables, doesn't work : it will give me a result but one group's weight adds up to more than 50%.

Below is my code. I have reviewed other threads posted here and couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

### Update

I think I found 2 problems.

1. groupCodes need to be sorted so that I can sum up their weights.
2. Somehow I am not setting up the constraints correctly. If I explicitly set up a constraint explicitly like

   ```
   {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  ub - np.sum(x[2:30])}
   ```

It works as expected. So it must be something with the expression `ub - np.sum(x[indexes[0]:(indexes[-1]+1)])` that's not working properly.

The faulty result essentially ignores the constraints and the group weights can sum up to 61%.

**[Update 2]**
I figured out the problem. I needed to assign indexes[0] to a variable(e.g. start) and then indexes[-1] + 1 to another variable(e.g. end) and use these 2 variables in the lambda function. Then it works. Thanks everyone.

```
start = indexes[0]
end = indexes[-1] + 1
ubdict = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: ub - np.sum(x[(start:end])}
```

**[Update 3]**
Actually I was wrong. Not sure how it worked for that one time but it stopped working again. It definitely has something to do with how to bind or persist local variables at the time the function is defined, not when it's invoked. In my cases, indexes only has the last values saved and therefore used in all the group constraints. I've looked at some other threads where using default arguments seem to work. But I can't get it to work here. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import operator as op
import scipy.optimize as sco

def fun_Returns(weights, returns):
    return -np.sum(returns * weights)

def fun_Constraints(groupCodes):
    uniqueGroupCodes = set(groupCodes)
    # Weights should sum up to 1
    group_cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  np.sum(x) - 1}]

    for code in uniqueGroupCodes:
        if isinstance(pd.Index(groupCodes).get_loc(code), int):
            indexes = [pd.Index(groupCodes).get_loc(code)]
        else:
            indexes = np.where(pd.Index(groupCodes).get_loc(code))[0].tolist()
        ub = 0.5
        ubdict = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: ub - np.sum(x[indexes[0]:(indexes[-1] + 1)])}
        group_cons.append(ubdict)

    return group_cons

groupCodes = [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 25, 15, 15, 25, 20, 20, 15, 15, 15, 20, 15, 25, 30, 15, 25, 15, 30, 20, 15, 15, 15, 20, 15, 15, 15, 50, 15, 20, 15, 25, 25, 20, 10, 20, 20, 15, 20, 15, 15, 15, 20, 15, 10, 15, 15]
groupCodes2 = [1, 2,   3,   2,    1,    3,    3,   2,   2,   1]
returns2 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.05, 0.03, 0.72, 0.6, 0, 0.02, 0.1]
returns = 5 * [0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.05, 0.03, 0.72, 0.6, 0, 0.02, 0.1]
cons = fun_Constraints(groupCodes)
cons2 = fun_Constraints(groupCodes2)
weightCaps = [0.0406, 0.0164, 0.0098, 0.0138, 0.0289, 0.0134, 0.0500, 0.0254, 0.0124, 0.0066, 0.0248, 0.0075, 0.0500, 0.0210, 0.0215, 0.0500, 0.0500, 0.0108, 0.0471, 0.0372, 0.0397, 0.0083, 0.0113, 0.0250, 0.0142, 0.0484, 0.0174, 0.0352, 0.0423, 0.0500, 0.0500, 0.0438, 0.0388, 0.0133, 0.0111, 0.0500, 0.0128, 0.0336, 0.0086, 0.0147, 0.0301, 0.0316, 0.0300, 0.0403, 0.0500, 0.0169, 0.0137, 0.0500, 0.0118, 0.0086]
bnds = list(zip(50 * [0.0005], weightCaps))
bnds2 = list(zip(10 * [0.00], 10 * [0.5]))
uncappedWeights = [0.0293, 0.0116, 0.0064, 0.0089, 0.0179, 0.0080, 0.0507, 0.0151, 0.0070, 0.0036, 0.0135, 0.0041, 0.1441, 0.0112, 0.0110, 0.0311, 0.0278, 0.0053, 0.0228, 0.0180, 0.0190, 0.0040, 0.0054, 0.0117, 0.0066, 0.0224, 0.0079, 0.0159, 0.0185, 0.0381, 0.0986, 0.0181, 0.0159, 0.0054, 0.0045, 0.0217, 0.0052, 0.0135, 0.0034, 0.0058, 0.0113, 0.0118, 0.0110, 0.0144, 0.0457, 0.0058, 0.0054, 0.0977, 0.0046, 0.0033]

init_guess = 50 * [1. / 50,]
init_guess2 = 10 * [1. / 10,]

# Optimize
optResults2 = sco.minimize(fun_Returns, init_guess2, args =(returns2) ,method='SLSQP', bounds = tuple(bnds2), constraints = cons2, tol = 1e-10)
optResults = sco.minimize(fun_Returns, init_guess, args =(returns) ,method='SLSQP', bounds = tuple(bnds), constraints = cons, tol = 1e-10)
optResults2.x.round(1)
optResults.x.round(5)
```

Comment: Can you show a console output of (a) a good run, and (b) a faulty run? If the output is too big then I wonder if just (b) would suffice. Readers may wish to see by how much the one one group's weight goes over 50%.